# Chi-squared test lookup table - how to calculate?

Tags: chi-squared

How to calculate the values in a chi-squared lookup table? I have to run tests with much higher degrees of freedom (still discrete values, but in the millions) than most tables include.

Comment: There are closed-forms which I do not remember at the moment unfortunately. Be careful with a large number of degrees of freedom. The power of the test is low, if we use too many degrees of freedom. Because of this, usually classes are used in which the observed value can fall.